# Why doesn't Angular update the ng-show status when I use an expression?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, ng-show, angularjs-ng-show

I have no problem getting ng-show to work when I use a scoped variable:

(excerpt from html file:)

```
<li ng-show="hasBattery">
  <span>Battery</span>
  <dl>
    <dt>Type</dt>
    <dd>{{phone.battery.type}}</dd>
  </dl>
</li>
```

using the following controller code, which works fine:

```
phonecatControllers.controller('PhoneDetailCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', '$http',
  function($scope, $routeParams, $http) {

    function loadData() {
      // fyi, the ?date nonsense below is to avoid browser cacheing of the json file 
      $http.get('phones/' + $routeParams.phoneId + '.json' + '?' + 
                new Date().getTime()).success(function(data) {
        $scope.phone = data; 
        $scope.hasBattery = !$scope.isEmpty($scope.phone.battery.type);
        // should i call some form of $scope.$apply() here? when i do,
        // i get a digest already in progress error. ng-show seems to 
        // update fine without a call to $apply
      });
    };

    $scope.isEmpty = function(str) {
      var retVal = (typeof(str) === undefined || !str || 0 === str.length);
      alert("isempty: returning " + retVal);
      return retVal;
    };

    $scope.hasBattery = false;
    loadData();
  }
]);
```

Like I said, that works. When I view a page whose phone.battery.type is undefined or blank, ng-show correctly hides the div. When I view a page whose phone.battery.type is a non-empty string, ng-show correctly shows the div. All good.

**Here's my question:** when I use the !isEmpty(...) call directly in the ng-show expression, instead of using $scope.hasBattery as an intermediary, **it doesn't work.**

Here's my code for that version:

```
<li ng-show="{{!isEmpty(phone.battery.type)}}">
  <span>Battery</span>
  <dl>
    <dt>Type</dt>
    <dd>{{phone.battery.type}}</dd>
  </dl>
</li>
```

controller, with hasBattery removed:

```
phonecatControllers.controller('PhoneDetailCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', '$http',
  function($scope, $routeParams, $http) {

    function loadData() {
      $http.get('phones/' + $routeParams.phoneId + '.json' + '?' + new Date().getTime()).success(function(data) {
        $scope.phone = data; 
        // no longer do any evaluation of isEmpty here.
        // as before, I'm not calling $scope.$apply() at all
      });
    };

    // same code as before
    $scope.isEmpty = function(str) {
      var retVal = (typeof(str) === undefined || !str || 0 === str.length);
      alert("isempty: returning " + retVal);
      return retVal;
    };

    loadData();
  }
]);
```

When I load a page whose phone.battery.type is a non-empty string, which I want ng-show to show, it fails to show the div. I see that isEmpty is indeed being called after the data loads, and is correctly returning false (so that ng-show's expression, !isEmpty(...), is true). But it seems like Angular is not doing anything with the value of this expression!

[image: alert dialog box shows that isEmpty is being called and correctly returning false]
.

Any idea what's going on? I would think this was a $scope.$apply problem, like I've seen elsewhere on SO, but the expression does seem to be being evaluated using up to date data.

Comment: Why the {{ }} for the expression ?

Comment: i don't have much experience with angular, but shouldn't it be `<li ng-show="!isEmpty(phone.battery.type)">` instead of `<li ng-show="{{!isEmpty(phone.battery.type)}}">`

Comment: When you evaluate an expression inside ng-show/ng-if etc. with {{}} it gets evaluated only once.

Comment: @Razah - don't think so. See: http://www.whitneyland.com/2013/02/why-does-angularjs-sometimes-use-single-braces-sometimes-double-braces-and-sometimes-no-braces.html

Comment: @Mohammad but I'm seeing the alert called at least twice. And the last time it is called, isEmpty is returning false. So shouldn't that return value be used? Yet ng-show doesn't show the div.

Comment: @Cyril because Eg.: http://www.whitneyland.com/2013/02/why-does-angularjs-sometimes-use-single-braces-sometimes-double-braces-and-sometimes-no-braces.html

Comment: @Benjamin the link you provided is already more than 1 year old. The author might be using a different version of angularJS which behaves differently. Did you just try removing the `{{ }}` to see if anything changes ? See this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17444394/angularjs-ng-show-ng-hide-expression-not-evaluated

Answer (score 0):

It appears that {{ }} notation means that Angular only ***evaluates and uses*** the expression inside the braces once.

Sounds like either Angular changed its handling of braces in the last year or so, or this blog entry I've been using is wrong: http://www.whitneyland.com/2013/02/why-does-angularjs-sometimes-use-single-braces-sometimes-double-braces-and-sometimes-no-braces.html

Commenters Cyril DD, Razah and Mohammad Sepahvand, thanks for pointing out that dropping the {{ }} solves my problem.

I'm still very surprised that Angular seems to be ***evaluating*** the expression more than once -- many times, in fact, as evidences by the 12 or so times I have to dismiss the alert() called from isEmpty!

Why would Angular evaluate an expression that it knows it's not going to do anything with?

Comment: No wait, {{ }} can be evaluated many times -- eg, bound variables such as demonstrated in https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_09 -- but ***in an angular directive string***, like ng-show="...", it will be ***used*** only once. or at least this is what i gather, still hoping i can find some guide that makes this stuff clearer!